# Can anyone tell me how to make an image of a disc in ubuntu that later I can mount and use?

Tags: software-recommendation, mount, cd-image

I am trying to find an application that makes iso or whatever usable type of images of a disc. I'd like something that is not command-based but has a nice graphical interface.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The GUI application to make ISO or other images of a disc in Ubuntu is **[Brasero](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/brasero/)**.

Here's a short tutorial video:
[**www.youtube.com/watch?v=GP6nyA-Pvk8**](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GP6nyA-Pvk8)

Comment: Thanks for the video/tutorial. I was just missing that to understand how brasero makes images. :D

Answer (score 3):

There are several graphical applications that will do this for you. Personally I prefer K3b. It is a KDE application and some people object to having to install KDE libs, but, it is both easy to use and very reliable.

What you will want to do is 'rip' the CD

[image: K3B]

You can mount or use the resulting files either directly (if you rip an audio CD to a media file such a an .ogg) or if you rip the CD as an .iso file you can mount it with gmount

[image: gmount]

Comment: Some KDE applications are really tempting, but I'm afraid of the costs involved if you install them in Gnome. I don't mind disk space so much, but **memory usage** what worries me most. For instance, in this case, will all those **KDE libs** remain **completely idle** (i.e. same as my unopened document files) when **K3b** is not running?

Comment: @Sadi I have heard / seen those concerns voiced over the years, but never experienced any sort of slow down simply because of KDE apps on gnome/xfce. If you are going to make such claims please back them up with benchmarks of some kind. I suppose it could be an issue with very old hardware with limited RAM, but you would run into the same problem, the limit here being RAM and not KDE vs gnome apps.

Comment: I'm not making any (implied) claims, I'm just asking -- really. For instance, can you tell me if you see any KDE libs, etc. running in **System Monitor** when there's no KDE application running? RAM is exactly what I'm worried about (I have 4GB) and I would certainly consider using a couple of KDE apps because they seem better than their Gnome alternatives. So I was just asking you to share your experience in terms of **extra memory usage**...

Comment: Well, every application uses libs. You would have to do the check yourself. Install K3b. Reboot, log in, open ONLY K3b -> check ram use `free -m`. Reboot, log in , open ONLY  Brasero -> check ram use `free -m`. With anything over 1 Gb RAM you are not going to notice a performance hit. To understand how linux uses RAM see : http://www.linuxatemyram.com/ and http://www.chrisjohnston.org/ubuntu/why-on-linux-am-i-seeing-so-much-ram-usage or a more technical document if you so desire.

Comment: Thanks, but this is not what I meant. Are all these KDE libs "completely out of the way" when you're not running K3b? Do they *only* become active (using memory, processor, etc.) when you start K3b?

Comment: See the links on how Linux uses RAM. I do not know what you mean by "completely out of the way". As long as you are not using swap there is no reason to be concerned that you are using 512 Mb or 1 gb of RAM.

Comment: I don't understand why you don't understand my question: "**can you tell me if you see any KDE libs, etc. running in System Monitor when there's no KDE application running?**"

Comment: Read the links I gave you and if you still have a question ask (rather then continuing this conversation).